# how can the product cards be aligned so that they appear as three inside the section in an orderly manner

Tags: html, css

The product cards appear always aligned to the left but rather it should be properly aligned in an orderly fashion to make it look better.

I tried using the flex property but the items then come aligned in a vertical manner which makes it very uncomfortable.

Is there a way where all three can be displayed in an orderly manner?

This is what it looks like as of now [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ecl5m.png)

Here is the html and css code snippets used :

```css
  .product-container
{
  padding-right:10vw;
  display: inline-block;
  overflow-x: auto;
  scroll-behavior: smooth; 
}
.product-container::-webkit-scrollbar{
  display: none;
}
.products{
  padding: 0 10vw;
}
.product-card{
  flex: 0 0 auto;
  width: 196px;
  height: 600px; 
  margin-right: 40px;
}
.product-image{
  position: relative;
  width: 196px;
  height: 350px; 
  overflow: hidden;
  
}
.product-thumb{
  width:196px;
  height:350px;
  object-fit: cover;
}
```

```html
<section class="products">
            <div class="product-container">
              <div class="product-card">
                  <div class="product-image">
                      <img src="images/card2.jpg" alt="" class="product-thumb" height="350px" width="220px">
                      <button class="addtocartbtn"> Add To Cart </button>
                  </div>
                  <div class="shoe-specs">
                    <span class="disprice">$59</span><span class="orgprice">$99</span>
                    <h2 class="brand">Adidas</h2>
                    <p class="spec">Running Shoes</p>
                    
                  </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="product-container">
              <div class="product-card">
                  <div class="product-image">
                      <img src="images/card4.jpg" alt="" class="product-thumb" height="350px" width="220px">
                      <button class="addtocartbtn"> Add To Cart </button>
                  </div>
                  <div class="shoe-specs">
                    <span class="disprice">$69</span><span class="orgprice">$129</span>
                    <h2 class="brand">Reebok</h2>
                    <p class="spec">Running Shoes</p>
                    
                  </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="product-container">
              <div class="product-card">
                  <div class="product-image">
                      <img src="images/card5.jpg" alt="" class="product-thumb" height="350px" width="220px">
                      <button class="addtocartbtn"> Add To Cart </button>
                  </div>
                  <div class="shoe-specs">
                    <span class="disprice">$89</span><span class="orgprice">$149</span>
                    <h2 class="brand">Nike</h2>
                    <p class="spec">Running Shoes</p>
                    
                  </div>
              </div>
            </div>
```

Comment: add `display: flex;` to `.products` class. remove `display: inline-block;`  from `.product-container` and `flex: 0 0 auto;` from `.product-card`

Answer (score 0):

Here you go use `display: flex` on `products` class.

```css
.product-container {
  padding-right: 10vw;
  overflow-x: auto;
  scroll-behavior: smooth;
}

.product-container::-webkit-scrollbar {
  display: none;
}

.products {
  display: flex;
  gap: 1rem;
  width: 100%;
}

.product-card {
  
  width: 196px;
  height: 600px;
}

.product-image {
  position: relative;
  width: 196px;
  height: 350px;
  overflow: hidden;

}

.product-thumb {
  width: 196px;
  height: 350px;
  object-fit: cover;
}
```

```html
<section class="products">
  <div class="product-container">
    <div class="product-card">
      <div class="product-image">
        <img src="images/card2.jpg" alt="" class="product-thumb" height="350px" width="220px">
        <button class="addtocartbtn"> Add To Cart </button>
      </div>
      <div class="shoe-specs">
        <span class="disprice">$59</span><span class="orgprice">$99</span>
        <h2 class="brand">Adidas</h2>
        <p class="spec">Running Shoes</p>

      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="product-container">
    <div class="product-card">
      <div class="product-image">
        <img src="images/card4.jpg" alt="" class="product-thumb" height="350px" width="220px">
        <button class="addtocartbtn"> Add To Cart </button>
      </div>
      <div class="shoe-specs">
        <span class="disprice">$69</span><span class="orgprice">$129</span>
        <h2 class="brand">Reebok</h2>
        <p class="spec">Running Shoes</p>

      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="product-container">
    <div class="product-card">
      <div class="product-image">
        <img src="images/card5.jpg" alt="" class="product-thumb" height="350px" width="220px">
        <button class="addtocartbtn"> Add To Cart </button>
      </div>
      <div class="shoe-specs">
        <span class="disprice">$89</span><span class="orgprice">$149</span>
        <h2 class="brand">Nike</h2>
        <p class="spec">Running Shoes</p>

      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove padding from:

```
    .product-container
 {
  padding-right:10vw; <--- Remove this padding.
  display: inline-block;
  overflow-x: auto;
  scroll-behavior: smooth; 
  }
```

then apply css in .products

```
.products {
display: flex;
justify-content: center;
align-items: center;
column-gap: 10vw;
 }
```